# Passing a string into a javascript function by echoing within PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Within a PHP file, the following code creates an HTML table and populates it with data from a mysql database table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>

    <script>
        function doThis(input) {
            document.write(input);
        }
    </script>

    <?php
    $sql = "select * from performance where title='cats';";
    $handle = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $handle->execute();
    $res = $handle->fetchAll();

    foreach ($res as $row) {
        echo "<tr onmouseover=\"ChangeColor(this, true);\"
          onmouseout=\"ChangeColor(this, false);\" 
          onclick=\"doThis(\"$row[0]\");\">";
        echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I'm having is that echoing doThis(\"$row[0]\") doesn't print the row[0] data although passing an integer e.g. doThis(22) does print 22. I think the issue is with the quotes and escape characters but I'm unable to make it work.

I'm using the document.write() method here as a test - before anyone tells me that I shouldn't be using it!

I'm a web design beginner so I welcome any suggestions for a better way to use data from my table in a javascript function.

Comment: "I'm a web design beginner so I welcome any suggestions for a better way": AJAX and JSON

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if nothing else you dont need all those escape characters which is probably confusing you as well as PHP.

```
echo '<tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" ' .
     'onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" ' .
     'onclick="doThis(' . sprintf("'%s'",$row[0]) . ');">';
```

Comment: Replace `doThis("' . $row[0] . '");` with `doThis(&quot;' . $row[0] . '&quot;);` (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Thank you - Using single quotes will make my life easier. I just realised that my method of passing $row[0] to the function isn't going to work so I'm going to have to rethink.